# how to use NSStream class to create tcp connection iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, tcp, nsstream

I need to send a string to a server on the same network with the iPad. when reading [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I found out that maybe I need to use the `+ getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` method but I am not able use it. In xcode I have tried:

```
//Try 1
NSStream *myStream;
//[myStream getStreamToHost// xcode cant find it]

//Try 2
NSStream *myStream2 = [[NSStream alloc] init];
[myStream2 getStreamToHost// I have initialized it and yet xcode can't find the method


//Try 3
[NSStream getStreamToHost] // does not work eather

 //Try 4
 [[[NSStream alloc] init] getStreamToHost// does not work
```

and by the way I am listening on port 403 with a simple program called autoit let me show you how:

I have two scripts (the client and the server);
[image]

first I run the server and it starts listening. Then I run the client script and when that happens a message box appears and a song starts playing:
[image]

Let me show you the code it is very simple to understand just to show what's going on...

the client code:

[image]

and the server code:

[image]

note that the client sends the message hello and when that happens a message box appears `MsgBox(0,"Data Received", $TCPReceive)` and a song starts playing shellExecute("t.mp3") that mp3 file is on the same directory of the script.

HOW CAN I SEND A SIMILAR MESSAGE BUT WITH AN IPHONE TO MY COMPUTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` is a class method (indicated by the `+`), so you have to use `[NSStream getStreams...]` instead of `[[[NSStream alloc] init] getStreams...]`.

Comment: I have tried that when I type [NSStream get (then press f5 to see my available options getStreamsToHost is not there)  do I have to import some Framework that I am not ware of?

Comment: iOS SDK doesn't provide this method.